# What does "fatality" mean here?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

In *Sweet Smell of Success* (1957), press agent Sidney lectures his newspaper columnist J.J's sister Susan, whose hang around the terrace:

> Sidney: You tiptoe around on those bird legs of yours, nervous and
> incompetent... with a **fatality** for doing wrong, picking wrong...and
> giving up even before you start a fight!

What does "fatality" mean here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means: you are fated to do wrong.